# Settings Provider in AndroidX

Tags: android, android-intent, location, androidx, provider

I need to navigate user to turn on Location for get current user location.
The solution in the Android is as below codes:

```
// either this:
    Intent settingsIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS);
// or this:
    Intent settingsIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS);

    activity.startActivityForResult(settingsIntent, 9003);
```

But in AndroidX, There is not any namespace for Setting Class that is in Android.Provider namespace!!
How can i do that in AndroidX?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It's still the same thing. AndroidX has nothing to do with that functionality.

Comment: "How can i do that in AndroidX?" -- you would use the same code as in your snippet. The existence of the `androidx` namespace, or of the Jetpack brand name, does not change how you would attempt to start an activity in the Settings app. Note, though that few (if any) of the `Settings` actions are designed for `startActivityForResult()`, and neither of those actions seem to be tightly related to location settings.

Comment: I just forget to add Android.Provier namespace and my Auto find Namespaces did not work.